# Could not find the main class: Snake Program will exit

Tags: java

it has been few days since i started to solve my problem ...

I have Snake.jar file which i want to start by double click. On my computer, it works with no problems, but whoever else on another PC tries to open it, he gets this error ...

My Manifest: 
Manifest-version: 1.0
Main-Class: Snake

In class snake i have main method, so thats not the problem and this .jar file was made by Export in Eclipse as Runnable JAR file

this is my Snake.jar Program: http://www.sendspace.com/file/w4buhs

Thanks for any help ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the jar was created with Java 7, but on the other PC is running Java 6 (which shouldn't be).

Did they already try starting it with

```
java -jar Snake.jar
```

Comment: That was that problem, thanks ... sorry for morbid delay